# added apple.schema to slapd.conf but Workgroup Manager still doesn't work

Tags: mac-osx, openldap

I've included apple.schema, apple_auxillary.schema, and samba.schema in the slapd.conf file. Rebooted the slapd service with no errors. When I try to connect to the OpenLDAP server with Workgroup Manager this is the error I get in my Console.

```
Workgroup Manager[46635]: -[LoginController gotServerError:forTransaction:]:
got error kNetworkError from request (null)
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try cross-posting this on Reddit... :o  Heh.